# Wait and accumulate values until other observable fires

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

I have two observables and I want just one value from each. In case the `observable2` pushes a value first I would like to wait and keep the received value until `observable1` pushes a value and push kept value then. Basicaly the same behaviour as with `skipUntil` with the difference that I don't want to discard the value. I guess it I could do it by concatting the observables but I would like to keep them separate.

```
observable1
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(doSomething)

observable2
  .take(1)
  // .skipUntil(observable1)
  .waitUntil(observable1) // Something like this
  .subscribe(doSomethingElse)
```

Comment: Isn't simply `merge()` or `concat()` what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will wait for observable1 to push and then switches to observable2:

```
observable1.switchMap(() => observable2)
           .take(1)
           .subscribe(doSomethingElse);
```

If you want observable1 to only fire once (for example if you subscribe to it somewhere else like in your example), consider using [`.share()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this is what I was looking for.